# Send table from Excel to specific people in Outlook based on content in Excel table

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The ask: to extract information from Excel, send the info to respective email addresses on Outlook based on the names in a column.

Eg: if cell contains "Mary", copy the entire table and send to Mary's email address.

I keep the list of names and their respective email addresses in a separate sheet.

This is the information, assuming range is A1:D5
[image]

This is the list of email addresses, in a separate sheet
[image]

Updated: Long data
[image]

Desired output for Mary
[image]

The idea: In the data table,
i) i want to look up row 2 (names) for every name,
ii) copy the information about that person into Outlook.

Eg:
For Mary, copy A1: C5 and send to Mary's email address.
For Tom, copy headers (A1:A5) and Tom's data (D1:D5), excluding Mary's data, and send to Tom's email address.

I am stuck on how to do a loop search. I only have the basic macro to extract data and send to Outlook with no name reference:

```vb
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set rng = Nothing
' Only send the visible cells in the selection.

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


With OutMail
    .To = "mary@123.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: If you have all of these custom cases, then you need to create an IF/ELSE or a Select Case statement tree that has all of these options. `If Name = "Mary" Then X: ElseIf Name = "Tom" Then Y`

Comment: It seems you just need to add some conditional statements to the code according to your business rules. SO, I'd recommend learning VBA and implementing this things in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the columns (from right to left) and hide the unwanted ones.

update1 - restrict to 5 rows

update2 - don't send if no column visible

update3 - reformat added

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsUser As Worksheet, wsTable As Worksheet, wsEmail As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, n As Long
    Dim lastcol As Long, lastrow As Long, i As Long, c As Long
    Dim sName As String, sAddr As String
          
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTable = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsEmail = wb.Sheets("Email")
    
    With wsTable
        lastcol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
      
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object, bSend As Boolean
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' for each user
    Set wsUser = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    With wsUser
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            sName = .Cells(i, "A")
            sAddr = .Cells(i, "B")
            bSend = False
            
            ' hide columns for not name
            wsTable.Columns.Hidden = False
            For c = lastcol To 2 Step -1
                If wsTable.Cells(2, c).Value2 <> sName _
                    Or wsTable.Cells(3, c).Value2 = "Beef" Then
                    wsTable.Columns(c).Hidden = True
                Else
                    bSend = True
                End If
            Next
            
            ' send email
            If bSend Then
            
                ' visible
                ' copy to email sheet
                Set rng = wsTable.UsedRange.Rows("1:5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                wsEmail.Cells.Clear
                rng.Copy wsEmail.Range("A1")
                Set rng = Reformat(wsEmail)
                
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                With OutMail
                    .to = sAddr
                    .CC = ""
                    .BCC = ""
                    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
                    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
                    .Display
                End With
                wsEmail.Cells.Clear
                n = n + 1
            End If            
        Next
    End With

    wsTable.Columns.Hidden = False
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox n & " emails sent", vbInformation
End Sub

Function Reformat(ws) As Range

    Const MAX = 4
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
 
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
      
        r = lastrow + 2
        c = MAX + 2
        Do While c <= lastcol
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastrow).Copy .Cells(r, 1)
            .Cells(1, c).Resize(lastrow, MAX).Copy .Cells(r, 2)
            c = c + MAX
            r = r + lastrow + 2
        Loop
        
        .Columns(MAX + 2).Resize(, lastcol).Delete
    End With
    Set Reformat = ws.UsedRange
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks CDP! this works just fine with what i am looking for!  if i want to add another criteria , let's say I want to exclude the column that contains "beef" in row 3, how should i amend this? Also, how about if i want to just copy the first 5 rows instead of all the rows? Hopefully this is not troublesome for u and appreciate ur help greatly sir.

Comment: @MingXi OK see update

Comment: Hi CDP! i Seem to experience an issue where it sends to every person in "Sheet2" - i have a list of people and their emails there and the code autoamtically sends it to everyone in the list (empty email) even if their name is not in sheet 1.

Thank you for the help sir

Comment: @MingXi Your example only showed people that were on both sheets, see update,

Comment: Cheers Sir! Happy holidays to you. Thanks for the updates, this is working perfectly for me. However, as i continue to add on my data, i realized that the columns are getting longer which makes it difficult to view fully in outlook. 
Hence, do you know of a way to replicate the above code such that it only captures the first column + first four instances of "Mary", and if there are more data from "Mary", then skip a row and display them below. Repeat the same for other users (if applicable) then send email as above. 

I know that the range restriction will need to be removed t00 See picture

Comment: Updated my initial post with picture example, "Long data" and "desired output for Mary"

Comment: @ming Xi That could be complicated, probably  build the layout on a temporary sheet.  Could you transpose the table so the years are rows ?

Comment: thank you for replying sir. Best if it is possible to stick the current format, if not then it is ok to transpose the data :)

Comment: @MingXi see update - you need to add a worksheet called Email to your workbook.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! This is working perfectly for me and I cannot thank you enough. Wishing you and your family a joyous holiday season, take care!